# Input Multiple Field Values into a New Field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-formula

I am attempting to create a new field in a search that pulls from other fields in order to automate the writing of a search query for another application.

the basic idea:

```
eval PCAP_Search=(( ipv4_initiator="src_ip" and port_initiator="src_port" and ipv4_responder="dest_ip" and port_responder="dest_port"))
```

with `src_ip`, `src_port`, `dest_ip`, `dest_port` being the other fields I am attempting to pull from.

I know I will have to escape the special characters and the ANDs, but have not been able to figure out how. The output of the field would ideally look like this:

```
(ipv4_initiator="172.168.0.1" and port_initiator="1234" and ipv4_responder="8.8.8.8" and port_responder="80")
```

I attempted escaping the characters individually with `\`, and escaping everything that is not the fields I'm trying to pull from with ' ', but run into the issue of the expression being malformed or the field I'm creating not having anything in it?

UPDATE
***first answer is not correct, I'm not trying to create multiple new fields, just one with containing a string that pulls data from 4 other fields***

Answer (score 2):

The `format` command will do that for you.  Just populate the fields (or extract them from a search) and call `|format`.

```
| makeresults 
| eval ipv4_initiator="src_ip", port_initiator="src_port", ipv4_responder="dest_ip", port_responder="dest_port" 
| format 
| rename search as PCAP_Search
```

You also can do it manually using the concatenation operator, like this (remember, "AND" must be upper case).

```
| makeresults 
| eval ipv4_initiator="src_ip", port_initiator="src_port", ipv4_responder="dest_ip", port_responder="dest_port" 
| eval PCAP_Search="(( ipv4_initiator=\"" . ipv4_initiator . "\" AND port_initiator=\"" . port_initiator . "\" AND ipv4_responder=\"" . ipv4_responder . "\" AND port_responder=\"" . port_responder . "\"))"
```

Answer (score 0):

RichG did help solve it, I didn't know that using " . FIELD_NAME . " would call the data from that field. this is the soultion that worked:

eval PCAP_Search="( ipv4_initiator="" . src_ip . "" and port_initiator="" . src_port . "" and ipv4_responder="" . dest_ip . "" and port_responder="" . dest_port . "")"